# Can AWS support Hosting Saas

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp

I planning/just think to start a eCommerce Saas using PHP.

I was wondering can AWS support something like following:

1. One instance support multiple domain and some of them want SSL.
2. Cpanel or something similar to manage multiple domain (track the bandwidth per domain)
3. How many domain can one instance support?

I'm new to AWS this. So any others thing I need to consider 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Cpanel may not work as its often licensed by IP address (AWS uses NAT). You can track bandwidth on your own though.
3. No limit, depends on size of the instance, application you want to run, and traffic.

Answer (score 1):

> One instance support multiple domain and some of them want SSL.

**Yes**. Using Amazon's EC2 Instances you can have full control over the OS. This means you can point any number of domains to the one EC2 and host the websites on the one machine. You can also have multiple SSL Certificates on the one machine.

If you decide to use the Amazon Load Balancer note you can only have one domain/SSL per Load Balancer (although the one might be a wildcard). The good news is you can setup as many Load Balancers as you like and have one per Domain/SSL. You could also roll your own load balancing solution.

> Cpanel or something similar to manage multiple domain (track the bandwidth per domain)

**You need to make this choice yourself.**

A professional System Administrator will likely want more control of the OS and will shy away from using additional management software such as CPanel. CPanel has many features to help you manage multiple websites but this comes at the cost of flexibility and the need to maintain the software for maintenance and security reasons.

If you decide to go with Cpanel you might have to do some extra work to get it to play nice (due to licence issues and no support for NAT which AWS uses).
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=99221

See : http://cpanel.net/cpanel-whm/system-requirements/ "cPanel does not support NAT."

> How many domain can one instance support?

**Amazon does not impose a limit**, it depends on the size of the instance. With a variety of instance sizes you could host many sites on one instance if you like.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

M1 Extra Large Instance

- 15 GiB memory
- 8 EC2 Compute Units (4 virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each)
- 1,690 GB instance storage 64-bit platform
- I/O Performance: High
- EBS-Optimized Available: 1000 Mbps
- API name: m1.xlarge